# Entity Framework IDatabaseInitializer to recreate tables of a DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The Entity Framework provides very few implementations of `IDatabaseInitializers`. I managed to implement a `DropAndMigrateToNewest` like this:

```
public class DropAndMigrateToNewest<TContext, TMigrationsConfiguration> : IDatabaseInitializer<TContext> 
    where TContext : DbContext
    where TMigrationsConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext>, new()
{
    private readonly DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext> _configuration;

    public DropAndMigrateToNewest()
    {
        _configuration = new TMigrationsConfiguration();
    }

    public void InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
    {
        context.Database.Delete();

        var migrator = new DbMigrator(_configuration);
        migrator.Update();
    }
}
```

What I need now is an initializer that will not delete existing database (since we have multiple schemas built with migrations in it) but do something that is achieved in console with

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration $InitialDatabase
```

and then just `Update-Database`.

The `DbMigrator.Update` method takes as an argument the migration name, but it won't work with "$InitialDatabase". I dug into https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Migrations/DbMigrator.cs but was of no help ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution: `migrator.Update("0");` and then `migrator.Update();` does the job.

```
public class RecreateFromScratch<TContext, TMigrationsConfiguration> : IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>
    where TContext : DbContext
    where TMigrationsConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext>, new()
{
    private readonly DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext> _configuration;

    public RecreateFromScratch()
    {
        _configuration = new TMigrationsConfiguration();
    }

    public void InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
    {
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(_configuration);
        migrator.Update("0");
        migrator.Update();
    }
}
```